# Using the SeleniumBase module in Python, how to get URL of link that changes with each query?

Tags: python, html, selenium, bioinformatics, seleniumbase

**Here is the HTML from the website:**

```
Unique sequence file: 
<a href="/cgi-bin/elimdupesv2/elimdupes.cgi?id=4ROEFYUD&amp;output=unique_default.Fasta">View</a> 
<a href="/cgi-bin/elimdupesv2/elimdupes.cgi?id=4ROEFYUD&amp;download=unique_default.Fasta">Download</a>
```

**What's displayed:**

Unique sequence file:
[View](/cgi-bin/elimdupesv2/elimdupes.cgi?id=4ROEFYUD&output=unique_default.Fasta)
[Download](/cgi-bin/elimdupesv2/elimdupes.cgi?id=4ROEFYUD&download=unique_default.Fasta)

**The download link changes every run because a different file is produced. How should I extract the URL and save it into a variable to download the file?**
I tried this but it didn't work:

```
class Example(BaseCase):

def test_(self):
    ...
    url = self.find_link_text('Download', timeout=None).get_link_attribute()
    self.download_file(file_url, destination_folder=None)
```

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Download")
```

Or this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Download')]")
```